# Reference request: $\{ (1-x^2)^n : n = 0,1,2,\ldots\}$ as a basis of the space of even polynomials

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, vector-spaces, special-functions

Sir Harold Jeffreys wrote: $\dagger$

> Consider the integrals $$ I_n = \int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^n \cos\alpha x \,dx. $$ Two integrations by parts give the recurrence relation $$ \alpha^2 I_n = 2n(2n-1) I_{n-1} - 4n(n-1) I_{n-2}, \qquad n\ge 2. $$

So I did the two integrations by parts and got
$$
\frac{2n}{\alpha^2} \int_{-1}^1 \cos(\alpha x) (1-x^2)^{n-2}(1 - (2n-1) x^2) \, dx,
$$
so I had to ascertain whether that was equal to the right side of the recurrence relation. That comes down to this:

\begin{align}
& (1-x^2)^{n-2}(1 - (2n-1) x^2) \\[6pt]
= {} & (2n-1)\,\underbrace{(1-x^2)^{n-1}} {} - 2(n-1) \underbrace{(1-x^2)^{n-2}}
\end{align}
So my question is this: Is there some context in which it is standard to use the set $\{ (1-x^2)^n : n=0,1,2,\ldots \}$ as a basis of the space of even polynomials? What context would that be? In other words, does this fit neatly into some broader context of which this is a routine instance?

---

$\dagger$ *Scientific Inference*, third edition, Cambridge University Press, 1973. Appendix III. If I'm not mistaken, this appendix does not appear in other editions.

Comment: The integration by parts leading to recurrence looks like a nicer way to solve that. I think **(98)** in this [list of integrals](http://integral-table.com/downloads/single-page-integral-table.pdf) allows you to write $I_n$ as the sum of $n+1$ terms involving gamma functions. This would require expanding $(1-x^2)^n$ using the binomial theorem ... I doubt that writing the integral as a sum in this way would be useful, but who knows :)

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee : I don't think that writing $I_n$ in some sort of closed form will serve Jeffreys's purpose because what he needs is certain bounds, specifically when $\alpha = \pi/2$ then $0 < I_n < 2.$ Detailed information about the value of $I_n$ beyond that would distract from his goal. $\qquad$