# Special functions for understanding elemetary integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

In [this earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2410654/reference-request-1-x2n-n-0-1-2-ldots-as-a-basis-of-the-space-o) I wrote:

> Sir Harold Jeffreys wrote: $\dagger$
>
> > Consider the integrals $$ I_n = \int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^n \cos\alpha x \,dx. $$ Two integrations by parts give the recurrence relation $$ \alpha^2 I_n = 2n(2n-1) I_{n-1} - 4n(n-1) I_{n-2}, \qquad n\ge 2. $$
>
> So I did the two integrations by parts and got
> $$
> \frac{2n}{\alpha^2} \int_{-1}^1 \cos(\alpha x) (1-x^2)^{n-2}(1 - (2n-1) x^2) \, dx,
> $$
> so I had to ascertain whether that was equal to the right side of the recurrence relation. That comes down to this:
> \begin{align}
> & (1-x^2)^{n-2}(1 - (2n-1) x^2) \\[6pt]
> = {} & (2n-1)\,\underbrace{(1-x^2)^{n-1}} {} - 2(n-1) \underbrace{(1-x^2)^{n-2}}
> \end{align}

As I said in that earlier question, here we use the set $\{ (1-x^2)^n : n=0,1,2,\ldots \}$ as a basis of the space of even polynomials.

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\textbf{Note inspired by a comment below:} \\
\textbf{The QUESTION posed here is NOT} \\
\textbf{how to deal with this integral, and} \\
\textbf{appears BELOW, and can be understood} \\
\textbf{ONLY by reading what appears below.}
\\ {} \\
\textbf{AND this question is NOT about THIS integral.}
\end{array}\right.
$$

As I did *not* say in that earlier question, I attempted to ascertain whether the equality holds before it occurred to me to express the function I got as a linear combination of the functions in that particular sequence. Despite the triviality of it, seemingly being a matter for routine secondary-school algebra, it was hairy and icky until I realized that expressing everything as a linear combination of these functions is what was how it should be done.

So now my somewhat vague **question is** whether, in the context of elementary sorts of integrals like this, there are **OTHER** instances of easily defined special functions whose employment instantly reveals a pattern without which the problem is hairy and *with* which it is straightforward and has a nice pattern? Just as there are tables of integrals, would it be worth making a table of such things?

---

$\dagger$ *Scientific Inference*, third edition, Cambridge University Press, 1973. Appendix III. If I'm not mistaken, this appendix does not appear in other editions.

Comment: To me it seems as you say like undergraduate school calculus ... you integrate by parts, remark that it gives you terms of lower degree in your polynomial and so you make appear the integrals with the lower index. It seems quite standard.

Comment: @LL3.14 : You need to read the actual question. The posting clearly indicates that all that you suggest has already been done. Look at what follows that. That's where the actual question is, and your were clueless about that when you wrote the comment above.

Comment: I did read everything, but your question is "since this is a hairy problem, is there tables for this kind of things", and I just wanted to indicate that since it is not a hairy problem from my point of view, I think it is not worth it. But this is a comment, perhaps you will get better answers ;)

Comment: @LL3.14 : You still miss the point completely. The question is not about THIS problem. And it was NOT hairy when I expressed everything as linear combinations of those polynomials, but only when I did not.

Comment: @LL3.14 Now I have emphasized the word OTHER, whose meaning doesn't seem to have registered in your mind yet.

Comment: ok, I'm going to delete this question and revise it to try to avoid clumsy misinterpretations by the inattentive.

Comment: . . . and now I see I'm not allowed to delete it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: FWIW, there are known deterministic ways of generating such integral recurrences, for example the Almkvist-Zeilberger algorithm: https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimPDF/multiZ.pdf

Is this sort of what you're asking for?

Comment: @AlexR. : So conspicuous crude typesetting solecisms sometimes are committed by illustrious writers. $max(deg(a), deg(b))$ instead of $\max(\deg(a), \deg(b))$ and $\displaystyle \int_\alpha^\beta F(n,x)dx$ instead of $\displaystyle \int_\alpha^\beta F(n,x)\,dx$ and lots of stuff like that. $\qquad$

Comment: @AlexR. : I'm not sure yet but I think the paper to which you linked may be a step in the direction that I have in mind. Since no one else is posting any answers you may as will expand your comment into an answer, possibly with some comments summarizing the relevance of that paper to this question.